# Javascript modifying Navigator object

Tags: javascript, user-agent, navigator

I can modify the `Navigator` properties by using `Object.defineProperty()` or `Object.defineProperties()` (plenty of answers for this on stackoverflow).

However I can't find a way to do one of the following:

- Delete a property from Navigator object, e.g. remove
  `navigator.oscpu` (not modify as empty string) when posing as a
  non-Gecko browser (EDIT: I can delete properties that I've defined myself with `delete` but not the predefined properties)
- Define a method (not property) for the Navigator object, e.g. add `navigator.taintEnabled()`
  when using a browser that does not support it

Can these be done?

Comment: Dunno what you tried and in which browser. `navigator.taintEnabled  = function() { … }` works just fine for me.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, it works. I was trying to define it inside `Object.defineProperties()` like the rest of the properties. What about removing a predefined property like `oscpu`?

Comment: `defineProperties` should work as well, please show us what you tried. Regarding predefined properties, they are either configurable or not, in the latter case you cannot do anything about them.

Comment: `Object.defineProperties(navigator, {foobar : function () {return false;} });` This didn't work in Firefox, but I can do it as per your 1st comment `navigator.foobar= function() { … }`

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. You need to pass a [property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description), not a function. Maybe read again the answer you found that use it.

Comment: But It works fine for properties.... `Object.defineProperties(navigator, { foo: { value: 'bar' } });` Can you show the correct syntax for defining a method with `Object.defineProperties` or `Object.defineProperty`?

Comment: Yes, *that* works. Now replace the value `'bar'` with a function. Not the complete descriptor.

Comment: Great, it works. I didn't find an example for a method in the documentation (including the site you linked).

Comment: Well it doesn't work any different than `x.foo = 'bar'` vs `x.foo = function(){…}`, so why would they make an extra example?

Comment: Thanks for your help ;)